# How to call Solr from an HTML file

Tags: html, json, indexing, solr, lucene

I am trying to write an HTML page that has a search box in it. Right now, I plan on doing the search box using the `<form>` tag.
I also have a Solr core going that has indexed a file. I want the user to be able to search for a term on the website and Solr search the index and return which documents contain the term, back to the HTML page.
I have spent a lot of time googling but I can not figure out how exactly to have the search box call the Solr program and how to return the Solr results back to HTML. I am having the Solr query produce the results in JSON format if that makes a difference.
Any guidance on how to access Solr from HTML would be great!

Comment: you might need javascript and ajax to do that . See [retrieve results from solr using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742610/retrieve-results-from-solr-using-jquery-calls)

Comment: Thank you! That linked helped tremendously